# Auto Null Value on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a problem that can be easily done by declaring a scope function but I was wondering if there is a better way to make this easier

The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="activate" id="activate"> ACTIVATE <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="first" ng-disabled="!activate">
    <input type="text" ng-model="second" ng-disabled="!activate">
    <!-- <span id="clickMe">Click Me!</span> -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      app = angular.module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){

      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So this is the case. The other two fields will be enabled if the checkbox is checked and true and will be disabled if the checkbox is unchecked. What I want is, to make the fields go null or blank automatically upon disabling.

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/2EPuhRiR9OncV8z7q018?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the fact that it is not a good practice to put too much logic directly in the view, a technical solution would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="activate" id="activate" ng-change="sameAsAbove(first, second); value = null"> ACTIVATE <br />
<input type="text" ng-model="value.first" ng-disabled="!activate">
<input type="text" ng-model="value.second" ng-disabled="!activate">
```